# Problemas para instalar composer con Laravel en un hosting

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer

Estoy tratando de instalar composer por medio de una conexion ssh a un proyecto alojado en un hosting compartido pero me aparece este error y no puedo continuar

```
[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]                                    
  Filesystem exception:                                                        
  Composer update failed: "/usr/local/bin/composer.phar" could not be written  
  .                                                                            
  rename(/usr/local/bin/composer.phar): Failed to open stream: Permission den  
  ied
```

Estoy trabajando con la version 8.1 de php en sistema operativo Ubuntu22.04 por medio de una conexion ssh tengo instaladas las extensiones necesarias intente hacer un self update pero nada alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso `root` a través de `sudo`? Parece que estás tratando de instalar la herramienta `composer` a nivel global y eso solo se puede hacer como `root`. ¿Podrías indicar qué instrucciones estás siguiendo o qué ejecutaste para que te saliera ese error?

Comment: Gracias segun yo estoy como usuario root en ssh y el comando es el siguiente:
-bash-4.2$ COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install
Si intento hacer un sudo me dice esto
-bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: Ese símbolo de dólar (`$`) indica que eres un usuario sin privilegios. Sí fueras `root` te lo indicaría con una almohadilla (`#`). Tienes dos opciones, instalar `composer` solo a nivel del usuario o, si tu VPS no tiene `sudo`, instalarlo o usar `su`. Aún no me has respondido qué sistema operativo usas para poder indicarle como hacerlo.

Comment: ah perdon es verdad uso Ubuntu 22.04 igual intente con el SU porque es por el ssh

Comment: Ok, tenemos Ubuntu 20.04, pero sin acceso a `root`. Entonces debes hacer una instalación de `composer` local al usuario. ¿Qué instrucciones estás siguiendo? Es decir, ¿estás siguiendo unas instrucciones de algún manual o tutorial? Las instrucciones generales para una instalación `composer` local las puedes consultar en https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally , pero podrías agregar un paso adicional para agregar el directorio `~/bin` al `PATH`.